# Ionic Vue ( ionic serve /ionic build mode production with .env )

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-vue

I would like to know how can I use .env.production mode with ionic serve or ionic build

Comment: you can follow the instructions here - https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: I have tried using ionic serve --mode production and having .env.production but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Can you show us project directory .. it will help us to identify how do mange file structure

Comment: did you try just doing ionic build? also what is the output in the logs when you do ionic serve --mode production

Comment: this is my folder structure https://i.imgur.com/afAYr26.png and this is logs for ionic serve --mode production https://i.imgur.com/P8ulPWG.png

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but for anyone interested, just do

```
ionic build -- --mode test
```

It works with snyc too

```
ionic cap sync -- --mode test
```